# How to connect php to mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a search engine for a website and I've never used PHP before and I have been trying to connect my webpage to a mysql database using this code:

```
   $dbhost = 'hosthere';
   $dbuser = 'usernamehere';
   $dbpass = 'passwordhere';
   $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
   if(! $conn )
   {
     die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }
   echo 'Connected successfully';
```

but I also read not to use the mysql_* functions as they will soon not be usable any longer but I haven't seen that anywhere else.

My old code to connect is:

```
  define('DB_SERVER', 'serverhere');
  define('DB_SERVER_USERNAME', 'usernamehere');
  define('DB_SERVER_PASSWORD', 'passwordhere');
  define('DB_DATABASE', 'databasehere');
  define('STORE_DB_TRANSACTIONS', 0);
  define('DEBUG', 0);

  db_connect() or die('Unable to connect to database server!');
```

Should I just stick with that or use the code at the top?

Comment: This is specific to mysql. If you want potential independence from database vendor, you may want to look into tools like Doctrine. Also since you are building a search, you may want to look into solr or elasticsearch as those tools are built for search.

Comment: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly--net-25338

Answer (score 3):

here you go, using PDO.

```
define("SQLHOST", "127.0.0.1");
define("SQLUSER", "login");
define("SQLPASS", "password");
define("SQLSGBD", "database");

$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=' . SQLHOST . ';dbname=' . SQLSGBD . ';charset=UTF8', SQLUSER, SQLPASS);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sql1 = 'SELECT * FROM table where field1=?';
$stmt1 = $conn->prepare($sql1);

$field1="test";
$stmt1->bindParam(1, $field1, PDO::PARAM_STR);

try {
    $stmt1->execute();
    $result = $stmt1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    if ($showError === true) {
        var_dump("error query 1:" . __LINE__ . "-------" . __FUNCTION__ . "-------" . $e->getMessage());
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should not use define... This is a bad style.

Comment: Is there any alternative of `define`?

Answer (score 0):

This is explained at http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

You should use one of the extensions: MySQLi or PDO_MySQL

With MySQLi you basically add an i to the new version of your code (do not use the old code) further information can be found here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php. 
Otherwise please look at http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php

Hope this helps.